# I can't wrap my head around specific "this" binding

Tags: javascript

```js
var obj = {
  log: function() {
    console.log(this);
    var nestedLog = function() {
      console.log(this);
    }
    nestedLog();
  }
};

obj.log();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

and then i get

```
{log: ƒ}
Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, parent: Window, …}
```

Can somebody explain me why `this` binding is gone? I didn't execute `nestedLog` from global execution context but still i got `window` object from `this` binding. I can't really understand why it's happening. I know that `this` binding depends on execution context and if i do something like this:

```
var log = obj.log;
log()
```

it's obvious that i get `window` object. But when i execute `nestedLog` inside `obj.log` function, shouldn't `this` binding stay the same? Can somebody explain me how does it work?

Comment: `nestedLog` is just a local variable being executed without a `this`. Unless you call it like this `nestedLog.bind(this)()` or use an arrow function, it'll be window.

Comment: `nestedLog` is called without any `this` binding. It is not relevant whether it is a local variable or not. It is the way it is called that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`log` is method of the `obj` so this is set to `obj`.

> When a function is called as a method of an object, its `this` is set to the object the method is called on

`nestedLog` is not a object method so `this` is set to `window` object
In [simple call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Simple_call) of function

> `this` will default to the global object, which is `window` in a browser.

Use can fix this using [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
var obj = {
  log: function() {
    console.log(this);
    var nestedLog = () => {
      console.log(this);
    }
    nestedLog();
  }
};

obj.log();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```